# Zookeeper client API to enumerate all child znodes under a path

Tags: c++, apache-zookeeper

I know that the CLI 'ls /pathname/' can list all znodes under '/pathname'.
However, I'm trying to find a way to get this list programmatically from a client.

Comment: You've not mentioned a programming language. What's stopping you from running the same command in code as a shell function?

Comment: This needs to be a client API, edited the post. Language is c/c++

Comment: Did you try searching for anything? https://github.com/tgockel/zookeeper-cpp

Comment: I think I found it, it's getChildren()